# Truth Table Generation for the given input

Tags: perl

I want to generate a truth table for the given input.Suppose if i give input 2 the output will be

```
10 01 11 00
```

if the input is 3 the output will be

```
111 000 110 101 011 100 001 010
```

i have a code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#print "a|b|c\n";

for $a (1, 0){
    for $b (1, 0){
      for  $c (1,0) {
        for $d ( 1,0) 
        {        
          print "$a $b $c $d";
          #print $x = ($a & $b & $c);
          print "\n";
        }
     }
   }
}

print "\n";
```

above code is for 4.

i don't know how to do this without writing multiple for loops. Here for value 2 i need to write two for loops and so on.

can any body tell me how to tweak this code for several input values.

Any help would be great appreciated

Answer (score 7):

**Recursion**

Here is  a simple solution using recursion:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                              
my $variables=$ARGV[0]||0;
show_combinations($variables);                                                           

sub show_combinations { my($n,@prefix)=@_;                                      
  if($n > 0) {                                                                  
    show_combinations( $n-1, @prefix, 0);                                       
    show_combinations( $n-1, @prefix, 1);                                       
  } else {                                                                      
    print "@prefix\n";                                                          
  }                                                                             
}
```

Here are some sample cases:

```
> script.pl 1
0
1
> script.pl 2
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
> script.pl 3
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm no Perl expert, so you might need to clean this up, but if forced to use Perl I'd probably do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my ($n) = @ARGV;

printf("%0*b\n", $n, $_) for 0 .. (1 << $n) - 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Perl so this may not work:

-- loop from 0 to (2^n)-1, where n is the number of digits in your cases;

-- convert each number to its n-digit binary representation;

Comment: You don't know Perl but you want to answer Perl questions?

Comment: Actually, the question is not only perl, but also algorithmic. And this answer provides a contribution to the latter part.

Answer (score 5):

This is simple one line Perl code using module [Math::Cartesian::Product](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::Cartesian::Product).

```
use Math::Cartesian::Product;

cartesian {print "@_\n"} ([0..1]) x $ARGV[0];
```

Output

```
    
./sample.pl 2

0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1

./sample.pl 3

0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Comment: +1 I keep forgetting about `Math::Cartesian::Product`. I haven't tried this but what happens if `$ARGV[0]` is large?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generalization of my previous solution using [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::BigInt). This is an iterative solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Math::BigInt try => 'GMP';

my $n_bits = $ARGV[0] || 0;

my $it = make_it($n_bits);

while ( defined(my $bits = $it->()) ) {
    print "$bits\n";
}

sub make_it {
    my ($n_bits) = @_;

    my $limit = Math::BigInt->new('2');
    $limit->blsft($n_bits - 1);

    my $next = Math::BigInt->new('-1');

    return sub {
        $next->binc;
        return unless $next->bcmp($limit) < 0;
        my $bits = $next->as_bin;
        $bits =~ s/^0b//;
        if ( (my $x = length $bits) < $n_bits ) {
            $bits = '0' x ($n_bits - $x) . $bits;
        }
        return $bits;
    }
}
```

You can use the `%b` format specifier for `printf`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($count) = @ARGV;

my $fmt = "%0${count}b";
my $n = 2**$count - 1;

for my $c (0 .. $n) {
    my @bits = split //, sprintf $fmt, $c;
    print "@bits\n";
}
```

This will only work for `$count` values less than 32.

Output:

```
C:\Temp> y 3
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised no one has mentioned `glob` as a solution here:

```
perl -e 'print join "\n", glob("{0,1}" x shift || 1 )' -- 3
```

This prints:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

`glob` is very handy for computing string permutations.

Here is the above, in a cleaner, non-one-liner form:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $symbol_count = shift || 1;

my @permutations = glob( '{0,1}' x $symbol_count );

print join "\n", @permutations;
```